# CanCan not filtering @products in Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am working on a Rails 3.2 application with Devise and CanCan.

My user model is User, and I want to restrict the access to the Product resource to the ones created by the User. The relevant code snippets:

app/models/ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user
      can :manage, Product, user_id: user.id
    end
  end
end
```

app/controller/products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
       ..
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
...
devise_for :products

resources :products do
  resources :sizes
end
...
```

Everything is working as expected: users cannot see, edit, etc... products not created by them. But problem is that if a user access the product index at /products then **all products** are visible.

How can I do to filter the relevant products in the index page?

I have googling around, and try `authorize! :index, Ability` in the index action together with `can :index, Product, user_id: user.id`, but then the user cannot access at all at the Index page.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a authorization issue. Instead should you scope you query, in your index action for the Product controller. Eg something like this:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = current_user.products
  end
end
```

Comment: You are very right, of course. It's late in the night, here. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

in Rails 4 I am using in this way:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    Product.all
  end
end
```

It would filter all products based on your cancan abilities. In your case `user_id: user.id` would result in a query like `SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."user_id" =`